# Clean up the [programming-languages] tag

Tags: discussion, clean-up

The [programming-languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programming-languages) tag has many off-topic questions, requests for lists of things, and opinion-based questions.

The tag itself shouldn't be burned because it's possible to write legitimate questions on the topic, but it absolutely needs cleanup.

With that said, it currently has no usage guidance and draws a significant number of primarily opinion-based questions and requests for off-site resources.

Comment: Yet again, somebody tries to kill a [tag] that I added to the Ignored Tags section of my profiler.  Why do you hate me finding the kind of questions I want to look at and answer?